# Where is the Google Cloud ML Console UI?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I've configured a project to work for Google Cloud ML beta, using instructions from https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up. Currently training a model using the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/training. Everything works like a charm, except there is no Console UI.

https://console.cloud.google.com/ml/jobs

URL not found

We couldn't find what you were looking for. Try one of the links below.

Google Developers Console Home
Google Cloud Platform
Google Developers

Where is the Google Cloud ML Console UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, the service itself and the command line tools are up and running. The Console UI, however, is scheduled for release next week.

Comment: This has been delayed until the end of this week. Apologies for the inconvenience.