# Can't access to Machine Learning console in Gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am actually experimenting with the new Machine Learning API on Google cloud. All tutorials work great, Machine Learning API is activated, I can train models and access the status of the Jobs in the command line. But for some reason, I can't open the page https://console.cloud.google.com/ml/ to manage my models and jobs online.

Also, I don't have the Machine Learning button in the "Product and Services" column on the left from https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard.

Even if I can do without, I wish I could have access to this console to make my work easier.

I found the same question here: [Where is the Google Cloud ML Console UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795097/where-is-the-google-cloud-ml-console-ui) but the problem seems to be fixed since one of my colleague have access to it. Is there something to update?

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix to enabling public access to all is in the process of rolling out. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for patience!

Is it possible that your colleague was a member of our alpha program, and was previously whitelisted to the console functonality?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't think so but it might be because he is working with the upgraded account while I'm still on the free trial.

Comment: I do think its in the process of rolling out to all projects... curious if you found gcloud sufficient, and so you're not blocked? (its actually more capable than the console)